Is there a shared state in std::filesystem::directory_iterator copies?
According to cppreference, std::next will return an iterator to the next element without modifying the argument iterator (see the example in this page). However, when using it on a std::filesystem::directory_iterator it actually modifies the argument so that after the call it points to the next directory entry, as shown by this easy program:
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::filesystem::directory_iterator i("./");
    std::cout << i->path() <<std::endl;
    std::next(i);
    std::cout << i->path() <<std::endl;
}

which when run on my home returns:
"./.X11-unix"
"./.ICE-unix"

The same result can be obtained by a slight modification where the iterator is explicitly copied and just the copy is advanced:
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::filesystem::directory_iterator i("./");
    std::cout << i->path() <<std::endl;
    auto i2 = i;
    ++i2;
    std::cout << i->path() <<std::endl;
}

This produces the same result as above, which really puzzles me. It behaves like there is a common state shared between all the copies of a directory_iterator, but I didn't find anything related in the above linked cppreference page (maybe I overlooked something?).
I did my tests using GCC 14.2.1 on Archlinux.

The iterator category LegacyInputIterator should give you some hint.

"once a LegacyInputIterator i has been incremented, all copies of its previous value may be invalidated."

Pretty much every os provides a file listing API of the form of:
handle = findFirst(path);
do
{
  // Get file properties from handle
} while (findNext(handle));

As there's only a single handle for the file listing, std::filesystem::directory_iterator pretty much has to be implemented with a shared state.
See readdir for POSIX and FindFirstFile for windows.
Note that this is implied in LegacyInputIterator:

A LegacyInputIterator is a LegacyIterator that can read from the pointed-to element. LegacyInputIterators only guarantee validity for single pass algorithms: once a LegacyInputIterator i has been incremented, all copies of its previous value may be invalidated

If you want to iterate arbitrarily over the listing results you'll need to store the results in a container then iterate over that.

So it is pedantically UB to reuse invalidated iterator, than considering shared state.

@Jarod42 more unspecified than undefined i think?

Invalidated iterators are mostly like dangling pointers, So I really think UB, and not unspecified.

If the iterator is invalidated then yes, but it only says may be invalidated
